# I cannot upload an excel (csv format) file in laravel. ["INFO No publishable resources for tag []. "]

Tags: php, laravel, provider, maatwebsite-excel

I want to use maatwebsitw/excel in my laravel project, but even though I write `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ServiceProvider"` in the terminal I get this message.

> "INFO No publishable resources for tag []. "

I added the provider code to `config/app.php`

```
 'providers' => [

    Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
   
   ],  
'aliases' => [ 

    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
  ],
```

I want to import excel file to my project.

Comment: If you are using the latest Laravel and Laravel Excel versions you don't need to manually  configure the aliases and providers. See this instruction: "The Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider is auto-discovered and registered by default." found on the official documentation here: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html.

Comment: Again, from their [official documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html): `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config`

Comment: @sitethief I deleted the code in config/app.php file and it still doesn't work , I get the same info message :(

Comment: That info message you get has nothing to do with your changes in `config/app.php`